# Html5 Video : Is there anyway i can disable scrubber for during the first few seconds?

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, html5-video

I'm interested in building a custom video player in HTML5. I have no problem embedding html5 video media, just trying figure out how I can disable the scrubber for few seconds and after that other controls should be enabled? Tried few examples but nothing helped me much.

Comment: Is it OK if all the controls are disabled? Or do you want to leave things like the play/pause button and volume controls enabled the whole time?

Comment: I just want the scrubber & play/pause button to be disabled for say 3-4 seconds, after that everything would be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
videoElement.onplay = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        videoElement.controls = true;
    }, 3000);
};
```

Of course, without the controls showing you would need a way to start the video. If you have the `autoplay` attribute on, it would start automatically, or you could call `videoElement.play()` in response to some event (like clicking a custom play button).

If you want the controls to be disabled but still show up visually, you probably need to create custom controls and use the same `onplay`/`setTimeout` technique to enable them.

Comment: Hi, Can you give me an example?